# Designing a points based system similar to Stack Overflow in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, points

I'm not trying to recreate Stack Overflow and I did look at similar questions but they don't have many answers.

I'm interested in how to design a rails app, particularly the models and their associations, in order to capture various different kinds of actions and their points amount.  Additionally these points decay over time and there are possible modifiers in the form of other actions or other data I'm tracking.

For example if I were designing Stack Overflow (which again I'm not) it would go something like the following.

1. Creating a question = 5 points
2. Answering a question = 10 points
3. The selected correct answer is a x2 modifier on the points for Answer a question.

From a design perspective it seems to me like I need 3 models for the key parts.

The **action** model is polymorphic so it can belong to questions, answers, or whatever.  The kind of association is stored in the type field.  It also contains a points field that is calculated at creation time by a lookup in the points model I will discuss next.  It should also update a total points on the user model, which I won't discuss here.

The **points** model is a lookup table where actions go to figure out their points.  It uses the actions type as a key.  It also stores the number amount for the points and a field for their decay.

The **modifier** model is the one where I'm not sure what to do with.  I think it should probably be a lookup table too like points using the action's type field.  Additionally it needs some sort of conditional on when it should be applied. I'm not sure how to store a conditional statement.  It also needs to store how the points are modified.  For example x2, +5, -10, /100, etc.  The other problem is how does the modifier get applied after the action has already happened.  In my example it would be when a question is selected as answered.  By this time the points were already set.  The only way I can think of doing it is to have an after_save on every model that could be a modifier which checks the modifier table and applies them.  That seems wrong to me somehow though.

There are other problems too like how to handle the decay.  I guess I need a cron job that just recalculates everyone's points but that seems like it doesn't scale well.

I'm not sure if I'm over thinking this or what but I'd like some feedback.

Comment: Just a thought... you could always 'decay' points when a user logs in (do a preliminary check, some in home maintenance, etc).  That way it would scale on a per user basis, and those users that DON'T visit, well their points don't decay till they come back. However this could/would affect stats if you are looking for avg points etc. So there is a downside.

Comment: That is an interesting idea but I'm probably going to do some sort of ranking so the decay is going to have to happen at least daily.

Comment: Important question: why do you want points to decay? I'm guessing the answer is something like "because we want people to stay active to be more important than people that don't" or similar... however - consider the extremely strong negative reinforcement that occurs with decaying points: after a while many users will realise that there is a red queen effect - they have to spend vast amounts of time just to stay in one place... and that is a big turnoff for your more experienced people (who eg have lives to get on with outside of your site)... and may turn them off joining in the first place.

Comment: Now, perhaps you have other good reasons for it - but make sure you weigh it up against the big negative obstacle that you will be putting in the way of people wanting to join up. I for one, would almost never join a site where my points decayed... all that hard work gone down the drain simply because you want to force a fake feeling of urgency? no thanks. ;)

Comment: These comments are relevant because - your problem becomes much easier if you just don't bother with decay and just find some other way of encouraging your users to come onto the site regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to prefer an log-aggregate-snapshot where you log discrete events and then periodically aggregate changes and store those in a separate table.   This would allow you to handle something like decay as an insert job rather than an update job.  Depending on how many votes there are, you could even aggregate them over time and just roll forward from a specific point (though probably there aren't enough per question or answer for this to be a concern) but given that you may have other things like user's total points to track that may be a good thing to snapshot.

I think you need to figure out how you are going to handle decay before you address it in a aggregate snapshot table, however.

Comment: So this isn't my preferred way but it's the best answer I've gotten so I'll give it to you.  I didn't end up doing this project but I am working on something now I might use a system like this for. I'd rather just use someone else's existing reputation engine but I don't think there are any good ones out there.

Answer (score 0):

Now Rails has  gem to achieve this feature

https://github.com/tute/merit